# Is there a better word or phrase to describe a tangible and usable product?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm a graphic designer and I'm working on a new website. I want a category for things that you can touch, hold, and use such as booklets/books, car wrap, gift certificates, product packaging, etc. My other categories are 'Digital', 'Print', 'Video', and 'Web'. Would '[Tangibles](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tangible)' be best?

Comment: Yes, I think it would.

Comment: "Print" is already a tangible category. "Video" is ambiguous. "Web" is "Digital". Books/booklets, gift certificates, are "Print". Your categories overlap somewhat. Also _tangibles_ is a pretty rare word. I'm not sure people will know to look there for, e.g., "car wraps".

Comment: If opposed to virtual/immaterial resources (e.g. downloadable items), perhaps "material things/products" ?

Answer (score 1):

What about *artifacts*? (*Stuff* might also work, but it's used in the textile trade to signify *cloth*).